# Symfony. Параметры при PUT запросе

Tags: http, symfony, symfony3, request, put

При PUT запросе с помощью какого-нибудь REST клиента (например, встроенного в PHPStorm) данные попадают в `$request->query->all()`, а если запустить тест, то в `$request->request->all()`. Почему так происходит? Как корректно вытаскивать данные из запроса при методе PUT?

Контроллер:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test_put", methods={"PUT"})
     */
    public function someAction(Request $request)
    {
        $query   = $request->query->all());  //данные при запросе из клиента
        $request = $request->request->all(); //данные при тестировании
        $content = $request->getContent();   //вообще всегда пусто
        ...
    }
```

Тест:

```
    public function testSome(){
        $data = array(
            'param1' => 'value1',
            'param2' => 'value2'
        );

        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('PUT', '/test_put', $data);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Все передаваемые данные должны быть доступны в `$request->request->all();` если вы передаёте данные как `x-www-form-urlencoded`, и в `$request->getContent()`, если вы передаёте данные как `form-data` или `raw` (например, если хотите передать json).

Но важно также обратить внимание на заголовки, особенно на `Content-Type`. Из-за непраивльных заголовков PHP может вообще не воспринимать данные. Проверить это просто - попробуйте в Вашем контроллере распечатать все заголовки с помощью `$request->headers->all()`, и сравнить разницу при запросе из REST-клиента и при запросе из тестового клиента symfony. Это и будет ответ на ваш вопрос.

Но чаще всего работать будет следующее правило. Если вы передаёте данные как x-www-form-urlencoded, то в заголовках необходимо указывать `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Если же передаёте "сырые" данные в определенном формате (например, json), то `Content-Type: application/json`. Для массивных запросов, а также для передачи файлов используется еще один `Content-Type` - `multipart/form-data`. Почитать описание форматов с примерами можно, например, [вот здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms).

Обычно REST-клиенты делают это автоматически.

Я немного отошёл от сути вопроса, поэтому просуммирую:

1. В зависимости от заголовков и, в частности, Conent-Type, данные на стороне Symfony можно получить либо в `$request->request->all()`, либо в `$request->getContent()`
2. Чтобы понять в чём разница между запросами с разных источников, распечатайте массив заголовков, найдите там отличия и сопоставьте с приведённой выше информацией.